# GitHub Copilot could not connect to server

Tags: github, artificial-intelligence, openai-api, github-copilot

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HJK92.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QUIpD.png)

Someone told me that the problem was caused by a firewall and a VPN, but I disabled the firewall and do not have a VPN.

Answer (score 7):

> GitHub Copilot could not connect to server. Extension activation
> failed: "Timed out waiting for authentication provider to register"

You probably have **GitHub Authentication disabled**.
GitHub Autenthication is an extension that is bundled with Visual Studio Code.

Go to File -> Preferences -> Profiles -> Show Contents
[image: Path to open GitHub Authentication extension]

In the left panel, in the "Extensions" group, click in "GitHub Authentication" and enable the extension.
[image: Enable GitHub Authentication extension resolves "GitHub Copilot could not connect to server. Extension activation failed" ERROR]

Answer (score 0):

I also got the same problem and I did this:

1. Disable the extension from the settings
2. Refresh
3. Enable again

It worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

It's because network problem.

Edit you `hosts` file, and add

```
140.82.114.4 github.com
140.82.114.6 api.github.com
```

Reference

[ineo6/hosts](https://github.com/ineo6/hosts)