# Why my vscode github copilot extension can't connect to the server?

Tags: github, visual-studio-code, github-copilot

I have already joined the github copilot waitlist and received email from github, but I still fail to enable my copilot in vscode.

The error is:
GitHub Copilot could not connect to server. Extension activation failed: "Timed out waiting for authentication provider to register"

I open the Developer tools and find that
ERR Extension 'github.copilot' wants API proposal 'interactive' but that proposal DOES NOT EXIST. Likely, the proposal has been finalized (check 'vscode.d.ts') or was abandoned.

What's wrong with my vscode?

I've tried to add

```
140.82.114.4 github.com
140.82.114.6 api.github.com
```

in my host file but it still doesn't works.

According to the discussion [GitHub Copilot could not connect to server. Extension activation failed: "Timed out waiting for authentication provider to register" #11324](https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/11324)
I've also tried to enable my GitHub Authentication but there doesn't exist "profiles" in my preferences.

Comment: What kind of network are you on? Are you behind a firewall/company network?

Comment: Re-Signing into GitHub Authentication in helped me: [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75700615)

Comment: You probably have GitHub Authentication disabled:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71007828/github-copilot-could-not-connect-to-server

Comment: Re-installing VS Code may fix your issue.

Answer (score 1):

**TLDR;**

You will need to uninstall your VS Code and delete its data, then reinstall the VS Code. It should work and resolve the issue that you are facing.

**Old and new discussion on issue**
The Github discussion that you have referenced in your question is three weeks old; however, we had started another topic on this exact issue in the Github Copilot community and this issue is resolved now. Please view the detailed discussion at the following URL:

https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/50848  (I have added a brief of the discussion below for quick reference)

**Troubleshooting steps:**

You can start with:

```
[X] Reloading VSCode 
[X] Restarting system 
[X] Resigning the GitHub account from VS Code
[X] Reinstalling both VSCode and then, Copilot
```

It should work on the final troubleshooting step above (ranked easier to difficult-to execute).

**Returned error in VSCode logs (for verification and reference)**

Here's what the error reads on the latest install of the Github Copilot (v1.78.9758) in the output. The Electron developer console shows this output:

> Extension 'github.copilot' wants API proposal 'interactive' but that
> proposal DOES NOT EXIST. Likely, the proposal has been finalized
> (check 'vscode.d.ts') or was abandoned.

Comment: I'm experiencing this issue on WSL2 only. It's working fine on Windows. I've already tried restarting wsl. Any suggestions? I'd rather not re-install the entire vscode.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting VS Code's data and restarting it worked to enable both CoPilot and Pylance (without needing to reinstall VS Code or extensions):

1. Open keybindings and settings in their json files, and save copies to the desktop.
2. Observe the folder these files are located in. You will need the parent directory named "Code" later
3. Close VS Code
4. Navigate to the "Code" directory in step 2
5. Delete the Code Directory
6. Open VS Code
7. Again open keybindings and settings in their json files, and then open the copies you made
8. Take contents from each copied file and put them in the respective previously empty keybindings and settings json files. Save

You will have to add workspaces manually again. Tried also copying this file but it didn't work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I have solved this issue by **uninstalling Visual Studio Code**. Then **clean uninstall** ( User Info ). Then again, **install** Visual Studio Code.

Helpful Links:-

- https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/uninstall
- https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/linux