# GitHub Copilot could not connect to server. Extension activation failed: "connect ETIMEDOUT 140.82.113.5:443"

Tags: visual-studio-code, github, github-api, github-copilot

Here is the log:
2024-01-01 21:01:07.158 [info] [gitExtensionService] Initializing Git extension service.

2024-01-01 21:01:07.158 [info] [gitExtensionService] Successfully activated the vscode.git extension.

2024-01-01 21:01:07.158 [info] [gitExtensionService] Enablement state of the vscode.git extension: true.

2024-01-01 21:01:07.158 [info] [gitExtensionService] Successfully registered Git commit message provider.

2024-01-01 21:01:28.299 [info] [auth] Logged in as

2024-01-01 21:01:49.362 [info] [extension] GitHub Copilot could not connect to server. Extension activation failed: "connect ETIMEDOUT 140.82.113.5:443"

Comment: Check your internet connection and firewall.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/q/77160160/11107541, https://stackoverflow.com/q/75904268/11107541, https://stackoverflow.com/q/71007828/11107541. this might be a duplicate of one of those.